# sails: how can i read both xls and xlsx in sails.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, excel, sails.js

I'm trying to read both xls and xlsx file into json format.while i'm searching there is separate node modules for each but i want to read both xls and xlsx file in my application.Is this possible to do? yes means how?

I tried  excel-parser module but it need to install python.Is there any another way to do?

Comment: Is there an issue with just using two different modules?

Comment: No i want to read both xls and xlsx files during file upload.